# Possible ways to transform ENUM values into JSON_TABLE?

Tags: mysql

Using the following query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT("[", SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE, 6, LENGTH(COLUMN_TYPE) - 6), "]"), "'", '"') AS types
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='myschema' 
  AND TABLE_NAME='tbl_items'
  AND COLUMN_NAME='itemTypes';
```

I get a result like this one:

```
+-------------------------+
| types                   |
+-------------------------+
| ['a','b','c','d']       |
+-------------------------+
```

How can I have a result like this:

```
+--------------+
| type         |
+--------------+
| a            |
| b            |
| c            |
| d            |
+--------------+
```

I know about [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), and I do get a static list of what I want with:

```
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE('["a","b","c","d"]', '$[*]' COLUMNS( type CHAR(1) PATH '$' )) AS tt;
```

But this does not work:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT("[", SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE, 6, LENGTH(COLUMN_TYPE) - 6), "]"), "'", '"') AS types
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='myschema' 
    AND TABLE_NAME='tbl_items'
    AND COLUMN_NAME='itemTypes'
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(t.types, "$[*]" COLUMNS( type CHAR(1) PATH "$" )) AS tt;
```

> #1109 - Unknown table 't' in a table function argument

Neither this:

```
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE((
  SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT("[", SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE, 6, LENGTH(COLUMN_TYPE) - 6), "]"), "'", '"')
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='myschema' 
     AND TABLE_NAME='tbl_items'
     AND COLUMN_NAME='itemTypes'
   LIMIT 1
), "$[*]" COLUMNS( type CHAR(1) PATH "$" )) AS tt;
```

> #1210 - Incorrect arguments to JSON_TABLE

What I'm doing is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the drawbacks of ENUM -- the list of allowed values is stored in a BLOB, and you get to do a "fun" parsing job to get it out if you want to query the discrete values to make a drop-down list of values in your UI or something like that.

You are on the right track, but to use a CTE you must reference that CTE in your query:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT("[", SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE, 6, LENGTH(COLUMN_TYPE) - 6), "]"), "'", '"') AS types
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='test2'
    AND TABLE_NAME='tbl_items'
    AND COLUMN_NAME='itemTypes'
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT *
FROM t CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t.types, "$[*]" COLUMNS( type CHAR(1) PATH "$" )) AS tt;
```

Alternatively, just fetch the ENUM definition as-is, and parse it in your application code.

Comment: Oh, I was so close! I initially had all `NULL`s for `tt.type` but only because of an invalid type (my example was not using the actual enum for security reasons); once I changed `CHAR(1)` to the proper `VARCHAR(n)` (i.e. correct string length), everything works. Thanks! Also, I know this can be done in code, but where is the fun by going the easy route? :D